# QGIS 3.16: how to fix the position when open a form, Python Init function

Tags: qgis, python, pyqgis, position

When I open a form with "Identify Features", I would like to have it always at the same position (top left corner or in the center of the screen). Usually it moves every time I open it a little bit down and to the right and I have to get it back manualy to the start position.

I don't know Python, but I think I can do it somehow with the Python Init Code Configuration in the Layer properties. What code do I need to open the form on the top left corner or in the center of the screen?
I saw the [question from user99](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/133814/how-to-position-the-qwidget-form-qdialogbox-in-the-left-corner-using-python-prog) and [question from kadeem](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/111119/how-do-you-set-the-position-of-a-plugin-window-when-you-start-the-plugin), but I cannot bring this information to the Python Init Code Configuration from QGIS 3.16.

Which code do I need instead of the example code:

```
from qgis.PyQt.QtWidgets import QWidget
def my_form_open(dialog, layer, feature):
    geom = feature.geometry()
    control = dialog.findChild(QWidget, "MyLineEdit")
```